# How to create 2D array matrix using basic loop

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Currently I'm trying to create a sparse matrix with this declaration:

```
typedef int Data;

struct Element 
{
    int i;
    int j;
    Data value;
};
```

I'm allowing user to input number of row they want:

```
int size;

cout << "Enter the number of element: ";
cin >> size;

// Function to construct sparse matrix
constructSparseMatrix(size,3);
```

My try for `constructSparseMatrix` function:

```
void constructSparseMatrix(int row, int col) {
    int** arr = new int*[row];
    for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[col];
        cout << arr[row][col];
    }

}
```

But when I input any number then the application output nothing but stop working. My expected output look something like this if I input `2`:

```
Insert (1 ,2, 3)
Insert (4, 5, 6)
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction? Maybe this is easy but I'm kinda new to C++ so please bear with my ignorance.

Comment: `Element` has coordinates and a data thing. Because it has coordinates already, a 2D-array isn´t necessary at all. You could store all elements in a normal 1D `std::vector`and search it through if you need to find a specific element. Or, for better performance, a nested 2D vector. But you don´t need `new` at all, and if you have trouble with it, just avoid it.

Comment: Why are you making a 2d array if you want it be sparse? Those two ideas are mutually exclusive...

Comment: ...and another thing: Array indices start at 0. `for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++)` => `for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)`

Comment: Is it acceptable to make use of the STL?  Specifically `std::vector<...>` and `std::pair<>`?

Comment: @deviantfan How can I apply your suggestion without using `vector`but only with a normal loop? Can you post an answer?

Comment: @Pewds Nothing prevents the usage of loops, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault you are receiving is caused by this line:

```
cout << arr[row][col];
```

In that context, `row` and `col` are the dimensions of the matrix, therefore the elements go from `0` to `row - 1` and from `0` to `col - 1`. When you access `arr[row][col]` you accessing elements out of bounds.

Not to mention that your `for` loop also goes out of bounds:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
```

and will start from `1` instead of `0`.

A correct function would look more like:

```
int** constructSparseMatrix(int row, int col) {
    int** arr = new int*[row];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[col];
        for (int k = 0; k < col; k++)
            arr[i][k] = /* initialize element (i, k) */;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98ff465d215724a0)

Finally, I'd recommend a good book on C++. It's clear that you are missing a lot of the basics of C++. `new` and `delete` are highly advanced topics. I'd recommend starting with `std::array`, `std::vector` and `std::map` instead.

---

Sparse matrices are often not implemented with an actual matrix (array) of NxM elements; that is used for *dense* matrices (where most of the elements are different from `0`).

A possible implementation is with an `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, element>`, where you map 2D indeces to a specific element. For other possible implementations look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Dictionary_of_keys_.28DOK.29).

An easier alternative it to use [Boost.uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/) which provides various kind of matrices.

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve the result using a normal loop?

Comment: @Pewds What's a normal loop?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if not using `new` as your suggestion, is there any other way? Normal loop I mention here is like loop inside a loop to populate the value of `row` and `col` for later usage without using any advance feature.